# X4 laser sensor limited range

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After i run command "X4_SENSOR_CONFIG_4=1 roslaunch subt_example team.launch", the range of the laserscan in only coming less than than 1 as also shown by below screenshot:
[image: image description]
This was happening for the X2 robot also when i used command: "X2_SENSOR_CONFIG_3=1 roslaunch subt_example team.launch":
[image: image description]
But after i replaced the sensor part of the planar_lidar.urdf.xacro file with below code the range is coming fine for X2 robot:

```
<sensor type="ray" name="${name}">
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <visualize>false</visualize>
  <update_rate>40</update_rate>
  <ray>
    <scan>
      <horizontal>
        <samples>720</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
        <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
      </horizontal>
    </scan>
    <range>
      <min>0.10</min>
      <max>30.0</max>
      <resolution>0.01</resolution>
    </range>
    <noise>
      <type>gaussian</type>
      <mean>0.0</mean>
      <stddev>0.01</stddev>
    </noise>
  </ray>
   <plugin name="gazebo_ros_planar_lidar" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
      <topicName>${topic}</topicName>
      <frameName>${name}</frameName>
      <robotNamespace>${robot_namespace}</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
</sensor>
```

But still the range of X4 laser scan is under 1. I am running system with 8 gb ram, 300 gb free HD, ubuntu 18.04, and ros melodic with gazebo 9 as described in catkin install tutorial of this subt repository. But im not using any dedicated nvidia gpu, i'm using i5 3rd gen intel cpu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21126/x4-laser-sensor-limited-range/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like the Laser detects a part of the robots collision (thus you can not see the object but the scanner does)
I think there are two ways to fix it:

1. Change `<min>0.10</min>` to maybe 0.2 or 0.3 or greater so it will start outside of the collision

(1.1 or make the collision-Element of your robot smaller by changing the sdf/urdf)

2. Change your sensor to gpu_ray `<sensor type="gpu_ray" name="${name}">` and it will only detect visual elements in the simulation

If you have an graphic card i recommend the 2. way, it will increase the performance of the simulation a bit.

---

Originally posted by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) with karma: 350 on 2018-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on 2018-11-20**:
Ok thanks, as you mentioned, the cpu based lase sensor was detecting the collision element also, so after i changed the minimum range to 1 it is working.

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-11-21**:
Your welcome :), keep in mind that your laser will not detect objects within 1m.